# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int(How to convert 18 digits integer to datetime)

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I executed query below on SSMS I got error like **Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int**

I am adding screen shots.

```
select  dateadd(second, 132706767376983975 /1000 + 8*60*60*60, '19700101')
```

[image]

Comment: 132706767376983975 /1000 is bigger than MAX int ...... what would you expect to happen?

Comment: I pulled this value from the lastLogon feature of users on AD but I need date formatted information can you propose any method for solve it?

Comment: I don't really know what you are trying to solve. Perhaps you have an XY problem?

Comment: Question is clear!

Comment: @whoami What is the expected result? And what exactly is this number `132706767376983975`?

Comment: Given that todays date in Unix Epoch time is `1,626,249,414`, can you tell us what this enormous number represents?

Comment: This page https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12814.active-directory-lastlogontimestamp-conversion.aspx says that that number is  _the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since the 0 hour on January 1, 1601 until the date/time that is being stored_ so your calc is incorrect

Comment: @Zhorov I have a third party application which takes and reports users' attributes  from Active Directory,but I noticed that lastLogon values are 18 digit integers, i was able to see this value on datetime format by using powershell script.[datetime]::FromFileTime(132706767376983975) i want to make this operation via sql query

Comment: I'm trying to find the definition of what this number actually represents. I don't think the link above is actually correct. It's not Unix Epoch because it's too big and gives a date into the future

Comment: When I use this Powershell, as suggested in some links , I get a reasonable date `[datetime]::FromFileTime("132706767376983975")`. This link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromfiletime?view=net-5.0 actually says the same thing: A Windows file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.

Comment: The problem was solved via T-sql query below:                                                       Declare sayi2 int
declare date char(30)
set sayi2 = 1
set date = '1801/01/01'

while(sayi2 <= 10000)
begin
set date =  dateadd(second,13270676737698/10000000,@date)
set sayi2 = sayi2 + 1
end

set date = dateadd(second,3975/10000000,date)
set date = dateadd(year,-200,date)
select date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get something remotely sensible using this calc, which rounds up to minutes:

```
DECLARE @Input BIGINT =  
132706767376983975 / 10000000

SELECT @Input = @Input / 60


select dateadd(minute, @Input, CAST('1601-01-01' AS DATETIME2(7)))
```

> 2021-07-13 19:05:00.0000000

This isn't quite the same as the correct answer though (powershell)

```
[datetime]::FromFileTime("132706767376983975")
```

> Wednesday, 14 July 2021 5:05:37 AM

But I'm guessing this has to do with time zones.

Answer (score 0):

The `dateadd` function expects to add an integer value as parameter.

Integer values are from `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`, and your value is quite bigger than this, even divided by `1000`.

If you want to use the `dateadd` function for this operation, you will need to split the add operation in several ones, all of them inside the allowed integer values, or use another datepart different than seconds.